# jQuery, problema al deseleccionar el elemento seleccionado en varios dropbox que cambian dinámicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo varios dropbox y quiero que al seleccionar una opción en uno de ellos, el resto cambie a dicha opción. Los **id's** y los **vals** cambian dinámicamente, por lo que no puedo usarlos para seleccionarlos, en su lugar uso el **text** de cada opción, que sí es el mismo y la letra 'a' de los id's que es común a todos.

El problema lo tengo en que si selecciono un valor en uno de ellos, todos cambian (aquí bien), pero si vuelvo a una opción previa, ya no cambian.
Viendo el código fuente dinámicamente, lo que sucede es que a las opciones se les va añadiendo el atributo `selected="selected"` y no se les borra el anterior, a pesar de que yo lo intento.

**Este es el código funcional que he hecho y me produce el error**.

```
$(document).on('change', "select[name^='a']", function() {
  var txt = $("option:selected", this).text();
  console.log(txt);
  $("select[name^='a']").not(this).each(function() {
    $("option:selected", this).attr('selected', false);
    $('option:contains(' + txt + ')', this).attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
});
```

---

```
<select name="a0" id="a0">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">80x180</option>
    <option value="2">80x190</option>
    <option value="3">80x200</option>  
    <option value="4">90x180</option>
    <option value="5">90x190</option>
</select>
<select name="a1" id="a1">
    <option value="6" selected="selected">80x180</option>
    <option value="7">80x190</option>
    <option value="8">80x200</option>
    <option value="9">90x180</option>
    <option value="10">90x190</option>
</select>
<select name="a2" id="a2">
    <option value="11" selected="selected">80x180</option>
    <option value="12">80x190</option>
    <option value="13">80x200</option>
    <option value="14">90x180</option>
    <option value="15">90x190</option>
</select>
```

En [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fffdd452/1/) está también.

¿Cómo tengo que hacer para que me borre el select anterior que tuviera el dropbox?

Comment: ¿No vale con el de jsfiddle? (lo desconozco)

Comment: Hola puede mostrar el resto, no se entiende bien a que te refieres cuando dices todos

Comment: El ejemplo que he puesto funciona bien, salvo que si seleccionas por ejemplo 80x190, luego 80x180 y luego otra vez 80x190, verás que en el resto de dropbox no cambia, pues ha puesto en el resto de dropbox selected="selected" en 80x180 y 80x190 sin haber borrado el anterior. Esto sólo se aprecia en el modo debug del navegador, con F12 habitualmente.

Comment: Pregunta, veo que estas usando `text()` en cuenta de `val()` que tambien cambian los valores y solo puedes usar el label de la opcion como referencia?

Comment: Correcto, no puedo usar los vals() porque se generean vía bbdd y puede haber distintos vals con mismo label, por eso uso el label como referencia. Tiene su por qué, pero resultaría largo de explicar y no aportaría a la cuentión en si.

Answer (score 1):

No uses attr usa prop

```
$("option:selected", this).prop('selected', false);
$('option:contains(' + txt + ')', this).prop('selected', 'selected');
```

```js
 $( document ).on( 'change', "select[name^='a']", function(){
  var txt = $("option:selected", this).text();
  console.log(txt);
  $("select[name^='a']").not(this).each(function() {
   $("option:selected", this).prop('selected', false);
   $('option:contains(' + txt + ')', this).prop('selected', 'selected');
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="a0" id="a0">
 <option value="1" selected="selected">80x180</option>
 <option value="2">80x190</option>
 <option value="3">80x200</option>
 <option value="4">90x180</option>
 <option value="5">90x190</option>
</select>
<select name="a1" id="a1">
 <option value="6" selected="selected">80x180</option>
 <option value="7">80x190</option>
 <option value="8">80x200</option>
 <option value="9">90x180</option>
 <option value="10">90x190</option>
</select>
<select name="a2" id="a2">
 <option value="11" selected="selected">80x180</option>
 <option value="12">80x190</option>
 <option value="13">80x200</option>
 <option value="14">90x180</option>
 <option value="15">90x190</option>
</select>
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Arghh, lo había probado con prop, pero no en ambos sitios.
Creí, que como funcionaba con attrib, no era necesario propo

Comment: Si es necesario en ambos, en la documentación explican por que usar prop

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está casi perfecto. El único error está en utilizar:

```
$().attr("selected", "selected");
```

La sintaxis correcta es:

```
$().prop("selected", true);
```

O:

```
$().prop("selected", false);
```

Acá lo tenés funcionando:

https://jsfiddle.net/wh0324Lv/1/

Comment: ¡muchas gracias!